# How to extract title from array of URLs using python, without getting an error?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

Below is the code that I am running:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = pandas.read_csv('activity_url.csv', delimiter=';')
x="http"
url_data=np.array(data[data.iloc[:,1].str.contains(x, na=False)])[:,1]

clean_url_data=np.array([urlparse.urlparse(i)[2].split("=")[1] for i in url_data])

title_data = []  
for pg in clean_url_data:  
    page = urllib2.urlopen(pg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    title = soup.find("title").text
    title_data.append(title)
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
HTTPError: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Temporarily
```

Comment: you are geting 30x redirection - it may be that link is missing "/" at the end or redirecting you to the login page - you need to check why, on a side note - use requests instead urllib[2] - it is much simple to use (and debug errors)

Comment: @Jerzyk how do I find out if "/" is missing?

Comment: check in the response where you are getting this redirect - you need to check value of the "Location" header in the response

Comment: Can you add what a bad url looks like?